# Providing LDAP support on top of existing Database authentication

Tags: java, authentication, ldap, virtual-directory, apacheds

I am working on a java application having Database authentication using spring-security.
It is very usual that, this application is used with other applications on similar domain.

**Requirement:** The need is that all such partner apps should be able to share common authentication with my application.
Also it is required to continue supporting DB authentication as well.

One way I found is to embed LDAP server like ApacheDS in my application so that other partner apps can use it to get authenticated.
In this case, I need to load ApacheDS with related Database records and keep it in sync programmatically.
But disadvantage on this is to have redundant copy of authentication data - one at DB and another at ApacheDS LDAP.

**Question:** Is there any way to avoid such duplication. By googling, I found option of having virtual directory server [Penrose](https://fedorahosted.org/penrose/) or [Oracle Virtual Directory](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/id-mgmt/index-093158.html). But unfortunately they cannot be embedded in application. Is there any way to provide embedded LDAP support on top of existing Database authentication?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I know very little about Spring Framework and even less of Spring Security

Having said that. I did face a similar situation, in my case, it was Apache DS as my app authentication source and client AD as the other.

My deployment environment was Tomcat and I used Tomcat Combined realm, which nests more than one realm for authentication. My app realm was configured to be one and client's AD was configured to be another.

Users could authenticate from any one of the realm, it worked. However, I did have to replicate client's AD users every night (including AD tombstones to mark them inactive), for authentication is one thing but other client information was also required, e.g. email, roles etc. and inclusion of new users.

I am kind of sure that Spring Security will also have the concept of Combined Realm.

I understand that this answer is not really an answer and more of design approach and many years too late at that; however, I wished to share my experience.